Should you rely on the factory-installed BMS on Li-ion pouch cell or add my own?
I'm looking to source some Li-ion pouch cells from AliExpress for an upcoming 1S battery project - something around 1000 mAh. Battery quality aside, I'm wondering if I should rely on the generic internal BMS that comes spot welded to the tabs? Pretty much all of them that I've seen just toss on a DW01A with supporting components and call it good. I believe the UVP threshold is 2.4 V which seems super low.
Is there a better approach? I've considered leaving the factory-installed BMS in place and placing a more-restrictive BMS circuit inline on the PCB - based off of a TP4056 BQ298215RUGR (Single-cell Li-ion protector BMS with 4.4 and 2.8 V protection thresholds). I've also considered removing the internal BMS and just using my own, but I really don't like the idea of "unprotected" wires running from the battery tabs to the PCB, even if it's only a few centimeters. I can't seem to even find unprotected cells in this capacity range. Is there another approach I'm missing or does one of these make sense?
Edit: Meant to say BQ298215RUGR not TP4056

If you don't trust Aliexpress batteries, why buy from there?

There's a world of difference between a basic protection circuit (the stuff in those cells) and an actual BMS. The former often only handles undervoltage protection, the latter would also at the very least handle overheating/low temperature, overvoltage/overcurrent protection and cell balancing.

@Justme that's a good point haha. For me it comes down to price. This would be a fairly low-volume run and batteries from AliExpress in my target capacity run something around 4€. I'd order some samples and do some evaluative testing to find a supplier that I trust. I think my concern lies more with the generic DW01A BMS that almost all of these pouch cells have, even outside of AliExpress. It seems like it provides the bare minimum of protection. Maybe it's just there as a last line of defense? I was just wondering if people really rely on it for their projects or if it's fairly useless.

@TooTea this will be a fairly low current draw IoT device peaking around 500mA (but normally sitting much lower). I absolutely agree though that I'd like to have more protection than what the generic BMS provides. Sounds like that's the way to go. That said, any thoughts on the best approach to implementing my own? Does it make sense to remove the "internal" BMS on these batteries or just leave it in place and inline my own? Also, this will just be a 1S 3.7V application, so I won't need to worry about balancing or any management related to multiple cells at least.

BMS and protection aside, how do you know there's no defects in the chemistry itself? Anyone buying components from Aliexpress is simply not a serious vendor and their dangerous, potentially criminal products are to be avoided like the plague.

@Lundin [wearing non moderator hat] : Aliexpress is a higher risk source than some others. It requires a higher degree of "due diligence" than some/many others. There are worse. || Some of their dangerous, potentially criminal products from some vendors are to be avoided like the plague. || That said: There are many good products at excellent or better prices than from most other sources available from Aliexpress. || This calendar year I have placed over 60 AE orders. In only 1 case has the offer been fraudulent. In maybe 2 I did not get quite what I wanted due to inadequate care on my part.

@Lundin  [Same hat]. IF one understands that AE represent a wide segment of suppliers, that a significant percentage have low awareness of what is offered, that  support is minimal or worse and that there are SOME thieves THEN with due care the overall value for money can be superb. || Finding a good supplier with small orders can gives confidence that larger orders will (probably) be similar. |||| So denigrating the a whole supply channel due to undoubted problems in some cases, when on average results can be superb, seems a somewhat marginal position.  Yes?

@RussellMcMahon And how can you trust that they sell you RoHS parts? They will of course say that everything conforms to RoHS when asked, but how do you know. There is zero supervision from authorities when it comes to things like environment impact and probably not much when it comes to product safety either. The business model over there is "scam until customer gets pissed, then find someone new to scam". To prevent that, you have to meet with the supplier in person and have dinner with them or otherwise they don't trust you and you can't trust them either...

@Lundin In most cases ROHS compliance isn't certified (or suggested) at the volume usually bought from AE. Few people have XRF guns - $10,000 + or under $2000 from Aliexpress :-).|| 1st order lead/non lead solder testing can be done on melting temperature alone and there are accessible wet chemistry tests. BUT that's very different than what people worry about in AE (or other) buying. || From having made many visits to China (plus 3 to Taiwan) as part of manufacturing development I long ago concluded that having dinner with the supplier is not enough :-(. My 1st rule of China manufacturing ...

@Lundin ... My first rule of manufacturing in China is "You* have to be there". || *Here "you" means you or a person authorised to make decisions on your behalf and totally "your' person and unswayable by things not on your interest. || My 60+ purchases this year do not meet that requirement. Most are related to prototyping an ongoing project. When/if it gets to the manufacturing point things will be dome differently. ||||

My main overall point is that GREAT CARE is needed, but AE serves a need which either cannot otherwise be met or which would cost vastly more, with the cost benefit not justifying buying through western channels in most cases. (Most). || Batteries are amongst the most risky purchases.

@RussellMcMahon Well if you don't meet with them at all, then you'll have to assume that they are not interested in doing honest business with you. As I'm sure you are aware, the cultural clash between east and west is pretty big. But there's a reason why many Chinese people themselves avoid buying products made in China - if it's not a quality product to begin with, then no amount of cultural understanding will matter.

@Lundin  I worked extensively with one factory. 10+ years on I am still personal friends with a few of the staff. We went to restaurants and shopping together and got on very well. When I was there we interacted very positively on production issues and they genuinely appreciated my contributions to the technical aspects. AND when I was not there I could not be certain that they would do as I asked, report accurately, ... . It felt bizarre. I have had variable experiences with a number of manufacturers and tried to understand the dynamics. ||

...One manufacturer stands out from all the rest (PV panels) has been as good as they get. I've visited once - well after they started making product for us. They are completely different to do business with than any other Chinese manufacturer and supplier I have met. || We had one supplier (LEDs) who made rubbish product that did not meet their own specs. They had fancy test equipment to show their results. Allegedly. I did lifetime tests in NZ with multiple LEDs and showed that their claims were garbage. They told my client that I was getting it wrong. By then he knew who to believe :-) .

Generally, placing two BMSs on a single Li-ion cell can actually reduce reliability.
However, if you prefer to operate the cell on a narrower SoC range or current-limited, you could use a configurable BMS, which will cost far more than the battery. In that case, adding a BMS to a protected battery would be unusual, not not fundamentally incorrect.

I know this question is going to be a bit generalized but I don't know a better way to ask: How do low-volume production runs typically safely implement a single-cell, low-capacity li-ion? Do they source cells without a BMS? If so, does their BMS live spot welded to the battery or on the PCB? If the cells come with a BMS do they typically just rely on that or do they inline their own secondary BMS?

Some have the protector BMS mounted directly to the cell. Others reply on two devices: a single-cell charger and a low-voltage cut-out in the load.
